# How to set python generated table for each value in separate cells *.CSV

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to generate *.CSV file (or*.txt). The script is simple. However, the generated *.CSV file is putting all values in one cell in each row. I want each value to be in separate cell.
Kindly advise.

```
from tabulate import tabulate
nestedlist = [["Point 1",0,5,0],
             ["Point 2",0,0,0],
             ["Point 3",5,0,0],
             ["Point 4",5,5,0],]

with open('GCP.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(tabulate(nestedlist, headers=['n','x','y','z'],tablefmt="plain"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
nestedlist = [["Point 1",0,5,0],
             ["Point 2",0,0,0],
             ["Point 3",5,0,0],
             ["Point 4",5,5,0],]

df = pd.DataFrame(nestedlist, columns=['n','x','y','z'])
df.to_csv('GCP.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: and same goes for *.txt ?. If I want to get .TXT file.

Comment: Yes, a `csv` file is basically a `txt` file. You can simply change the output filename. You can also set a different separator with `sep`. Check the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) for all options

Comment: Thanks a lot seems like issue is resolved.